# Get php-fpm version used by an Apache2 virtualhost

Tags: linux, bash, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I need to connect to a Ubuntu server with ssh as a root user and determine which version of php-fpm is used by a virtualhost (I know in advance the virtualhost config name).

I'm not the only administrator of this server and I can't know in advance how other users might have altered the configuration.

Currently I'm checking the active php-fpm service.
But users might have activated multiple php-fpm services with different versions. In this configuration I can't determine which one is used by the virtualhost.

My current command:

```bash
php-fpm$(ps -e -o stat,command | grep -E '^Ss\s+php-fpm' | grep -E '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' -o) -v | head -1 | cut -f2 -d' ' | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' -o
```

I know the simplest way would be to create a `info.php` file at the root of the website with a `<?php phpinfo();` content and call it with curl.

But I would prefer not to touch to the website content.

Is there an apache command line I'm not aware of that could help me here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if the answer is "multiple"?

Comment: If there is multiple services the above command will fail silently. But this command is useless anyway, even if it worked. This would not tell me which version my virtualhost is using. I know I can list the different virtualhost on my server with apache2ctl -S but that's useless too, I can't get more informations out of it.

Comment: My point is that even a single VirtualHost may use several different php-fpm versions at the same time – if your users know how to configure it at vhost level, then nothing actually stops them from doing the same at Location or Directory level...

Comment: I see what you mean... Then I'll have no other choice than using the php script then. Thanks for your answer.